# AngularJS Directive not showing templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Having some issues with my angular directive. The expected outcome of this application is to display Personal Trainer profiles from an array in the main controller, using an angular directive and html template.  I cannot seem to figure out why this doesn't work, code snippets are copied below. Console shows no errors and I can parse data binding from the trainers array manually but I want the template to display this...

HTML:

```
...
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="trainer in trainers">
      <app-info></app-info>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

MainController.js:

```
angular.module('reasons', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.trainers = [ 
        { 
            name: 'Mike',
            email: 'mike@gym.com',
            tel: '07191941249',
            info: 'I am a gym instructor',
            quote: 'Inspirational Quote'
        }, ... ]
}]);
```

`app-info` directive:

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'E', 
        scope: {}, 
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html' 
    }; 
});
```

`app-info` directive template:

```
<div>
<h3>{{trainer.name}}</h3>
<p>{{trainer.tel}}</p>
<p>{{trainer.email}}</p>
</div>
```

How can I resolve this?

Edit - So I added the code in its entirety [and I removed irrelevant sections]. In my project I am actually trying to link a template html document, but even just using 'template:' doesn't work?

Comment: Post more code because posted snippet is fine.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Post more code. I checked your code in JSFiddle and it's works - https://jsfiddle.net/kd44t9s4/1/

Comment: What is the value of "trainers"?

Comment: I will reply in the comment because the question is on hold: you need to remove the line `scope: {}` from your `app-info` directive -- right now it uses an isolate scope and it cannot see the `trainer` variable. Or you can pass the variable to the isolate scope: `scope: {trainer: "="}` and use like this: `<app-info trainer="trainer"></app-info>`

Comment: Hi, i've tried this but still doesn't work...

Comment: Hi! Have you checked your template url? If you want AngularJS to search your template relative to the base url please try to write your tempatUrl with starting `/` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this (somehow)!

I changed the controllers code to say app.controller instead of using angular.module to define the application. For some reason where this did not work before, now works and I am now working on integrating this into my actual project successfully.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.trainers = [ 
    { 
        name: 'Mike',
        email: 'mike@gym.com',
        tel: '07191941249',
        info: 'I am a gym instructor',
        quote: 'Inspirational Quote'
    }, ... ]
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the directive to:

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: false, 
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html' 
}; 
});
```

This should cause the directive to get the parent scope and make the data accessible to it there.

Passing the empty object to scope creates an isolated scope for the directive.